# Is hand coding required at all?

Tags: theme-development, customization, themes

With template builders like Divi and Elementor, is hand coding still required? We are building a B2B website on WordPress and there are no transactions involved in it. Our content will vary from page to page.

Answer (score 0):

Required for what? Building a template?  No if the template you choose is exactly what you want. Yes if it isn't.

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, we plan to build the template using a tool like Divi or Elementor. So, we won’t be choosing an existing template. In that case, is hand coding required at all? Is there any merit in hiring a WordPress developer and getting her/him to hand code CSS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are hungry. You can now go to the next store and get yourself a TV Dinner. There is much variety and you can get nearly every Dish there is.

However, you can not really get any Dish, and if you are feeling fancy, you won't be able to get, let's say, a Cheeseburger with asian Sauce, only the asian burger (which lacks Cheese) or the Cheeseburger (which lacks the sweet sweet asian Sauce you crave). Also, you get a lot of additional stuff in there you wouldn't really need in it, like the slice of pickle you always have to remove or the glutamate that gives you just a smaaaaall headache. Not really nasty, but it slows you down.

On the other hand, you can go to your store and get all the ingredients for your Special Burger. Nice fresh grounded Beef, Asia Sauce, two slices of Cheese and some Romana salad. While it will probably cost you more money and definitely will be more work, at the end of the evening you will have YOUR Burger, exactly as you want it. It won't lie in your stomach Like a brick and just will be perfect. Hell, you can write the recipe down and cook it for someone else in a couple of days. And if he doesn't like Cheese, you just don't put it on there.

So there you have it. Is coding required? Hell no. Are you limiting your Choices and have to live with the downsides of using a "one-size-fits-all" theme if you don't Code? Absolutely.

Comment: Thanks, that’s helpful. Just to clarify, we are weighing between hiring a professional WordPress dev agency for hand coding vs. using Divi to design the look and feel we want and then getting a developer to tie them all together if required. I work for a B2B software company, and we are all new to Divi. Do you think with Divi template builder, we cannot design a custom template?